# "Can keep on wind to go on and on..." minor key, female singer, heard in Starbucks

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

I'm seeking a beautiful song I heard at Starbucks

- It was sung by a woman
- the lyrics were something like "can keep on wind to go on and on".
- It was a melodic song in a minor key.

Comment: This isn't much to go on.  Can you give any more details?  Slow, fast?  What instruments?  Any more lyrics?  Genre?

Comment: You should have asked in Starbucks - aren't they normally promoting the music they play?

Answer (score 1):

This might be it since you did not provide much.  It features the lyrics

> Our feelings show, our luck
>   run out and **the wind** won't blow

and

> **keep** a smilin' face

[Earth, Wind & Fire - On Your Face](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IbTNgdxrpc)